# Is possible make a queue in html5 file api?

Tags: html, file-upload

I try to use html5 file api-
html:

```
 <input type="file" name="myFile" id="input" multiple ></span>
```

js:

```
for (var i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
   uploader.sendFile(fileList[i]);
}
```

It loads files in few threads, but I want to load files in one queue(thread) one by one, is it possible by html5 api?

Comment: @MeLight, yep, I think its one possible way

Comment: Ok, then there's your answer :) your `uploader` object should provide you with some sort of *finished* event, I'd use that to start uploading the next file.